# C create Multidimensional array by scanf line by line

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I am trying to get the input below and store it in a multidimensional array and store the last number in a variable.

- After each row,'\n' character will be given.
- It will be array of char.
- Dimension is [10][10].

Input:

```
1112231113
2112231113
1112231113
3312231113
1112231113
1112231113
3312231113
3312231113
3312231113
3312231113
1
```

My code:

```
int main(void) {
  char array[10][10];
  char in;

  scanf("%c", &in);
  while(in != '\n') {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
      for(int j = 0;j < 10;j++){
        array[i][j] = in;

      }
    }
    scanf("%c", &in);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 10;i++){
      for(int j = 0;j < 10;j++){
        printf("%c", array[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;


}
```

Comment: And...what have you tried so far?

Comment: What cod have you written? Have you tried using dynamic memory allocation (i.e malloc)? Are the number of columns known before execution?

Comment: so where are you blocked ?

Comment: i dont know how to read that kind of input.Read line by line and each line will be a row.

Comment: `fgets` or `scanf` to read line per line then iterate on the read line for each columns, or read char per char and bypass newline. A `for` for the line and an other embeded for the columns. (supposing 2D array)

Comment: `while(in != '\n')` if wrong and you fill your array always with the same character everywhere. You need to read the char inside the two for